# Weird behaviour with BearSSL on GPIO ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, pins, mqtt

I use GPIO 5 to trigger a relay. My code also connects with a secure MQTT connection for which I have to use the BearSSL certificate definitions.

Without the BearSSL certificates, when the ESP restarts it does not re-trigger the relay, and the GPIO maintains its state between reboots, but when I use the bearSSL certificates the behavior changes, and GPIO 5 goes low on restart. Any explanation why and how to mitigate it?

I am 100% sure it is because of the import, because I removed components from my code until I could find the piece of code that caused this, and it was because of the declarations.

```cpp
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h> 

static const char AWS_CERT_CA[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(aws root)EOF"; 
static const char AWS_CERT_CRT[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(device cert)KEY";
static const char AWS_CERT_KEY[] PROGMEM = R"KEY(device key)KEY";
     
BearSSL::X509List cert(AWS_CERT_CA);
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(AWS_CERT_CRT);
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(AWS_CERT_KEY);
     
WiFiClientSecure espClient;

void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  ESP.restart();
}
    
void loop() {}
```

Without the following three lines the LED on GPIO 5 does not flicker on restarts, but adding these lines makes them flicker:

```cpp
BearSSL::X509List cert(AWS_CERT_CA); 
BearSSL::X509List client_crt(AWS_CERT_CRT); 
BearSSL::PrivateKey key(AWS_CERT_KEY);
```

Any solution or suggestion towards a solution for this problem will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to move the BearSSL declaration and usage after the pinMode setting of the GPIO.

I had to make the certificate and keys local variables and wrap the entire setting up of WiFi, connecting to it, setting up and connecting to the AWS core in a single function after setting up the GPIO pins.

```cpp
void setupWiFiAndConnectAWS() {
  BearSSL::X509List cert(AWS_CERT_CA);
  BearSSL::X509List client_crt(AWS_CERT_CRT);
  BearSSL::PrivateKey key(AWS_CERT_KEY);
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  DEBUG_MSG("[setupWiFi] Setting host name\n");
  WiFi.hostname(deviceId);
  DEBUG_MSG("[setupWiFi] Setting station mode\n");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  if (WiFi.getMode() & WIFI_AP) {
    WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
  }

  WiFi.persistent(false);
  DEBUG_MSG("[setupWiFi] Loading certificates\n");
  net.setTrustAnchors(&cert);
  net.setClientRSACert(&client_crt, &key);
  loadCredentials();
  connectWiFi();
  attachInputInterrupts(false);
  setupNTP();
  connectAWS();
}
```

Although this is a workaround, I still don't understand the core problem and would like to understand it.